# Reading incoming notifications in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, notifications, listener

Is there any way to read incoming notifications in Objective C? I mean something similar to Android's `NotificationListenerService` where I can read with my app, incoming notifications and respond accordingly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can through the method in AppDelegate

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

Answer (score 1):

You must first register for remote notifications in the -didFinishLaunching method

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

The following delegate methods are used to handle notifications from within the App Delegate:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken;
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo;
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error;
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification;
```

The `-didReceiveRemoteNotification` method can be used to handle incoming notifications at runtime. The `userInfo` parameter holds the payload with the notification data.

For an app which is not in the foreground, the notification can subsequently be found in the `-applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

```
UILocalNotification *remoteNotif =
        [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (remoteNotif) {
        //Handle remote notification here.
    }
```

You can read Apple's documentation for handling notifications [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html).